# Angular filter array of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, filter

For the past few days I have had difficulties with filtering an array of array with Angular and displaying it. I have tried searching for similar posts but I could not find solution for my case.

Example how my data looks:

```
$scope.answers = [
    {title: "Qestion1", keywords: ["dino", "dog", "cat"]},
    {title: "Quessstion2", keywords: ["cat", "dog"]}
];
```

Currently I am displaying a list:

```
<div class="solution-box" ng-repeat="answer in pagedItems[currentPage]">
```

I have two search fields:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="title"  ng-change="search1()"  class="form-control" placeholder="Filter by title">
<input type="text" ng-model="keys"  ng-change="search2()" class="form-control" placeholder="Filter by keywords">
```

Search1() function which just works fine:

```
$scope.search1 = function () {
     $scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')($scope.answers, function (answer) {
         if (searchMatch(answer.title, $scope.title))
             return true;
         return false;
     });
     $scope.currentPage = 0;
     // now group by pages
     $scope.groupToPages();
 };
```

Search2() function which does not alter filteredItems

```
$scope.search2 = function () {
        $scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')($scope.answers, function (answer) {
            return $filter('filter')(answer.keywords, function (keyword) {
                if (searchMatch(keyword, $scope.keys)) {
                    console.log($scope.filteredItems + '/' + keyword + '|' + $scope.keys);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
        $scope.currentPage = 0;
        // now group by pages
        $scope.groupToPages();
    };
```

Could anyone please give tips what could be wrong in Search2() function?
While I am logging filteredItems, it logs me correct amount of answers, but the list still remains of the same size as it was.
What is the main logic of custom filters that I am missing here?

Thanks,

Comment: I suggest making a jsfiddle/plunker.

Comment: `$filter('filter')` will return items where the function that you pass to it returns a truthy value.  With `search2`, you're returning the result of another `$filter('filter')` which is likely an array and therefore _always_ truthy, so no filtering will be done.  What are you expecting the inner filter to do there?

Comment: I thought  $filter('filter') works on one level of array, so with inner filter I wanted to filter keywords, then filter answers with filtered keywords. The idea is display list by filtering titles and keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mgilson pointed out you need to return a boolean from the filter callback function but you are returning an array which will always be truthy. There is also no need to use `$filter('filter')` here. You could just do something like this:

```
$scope.filteredItems = $scope.answers.filter(function(answer) {
    var matches = answer.keywords.filter(function() {
        return searchMatch(keyword, $scope.keys);
    });
    return matches.length > 0;
});
```